# Netcat or similar: Dockerized general purpose TCP/IP port proxy/gateway (for any service: mysql, ssh, dns, etc)

Tags: networking, proxy, gateway, netcat

## Context

We manage a radio station with 35+ workplaces for journalists. All them using a desktop application, connecting to a MySQL exposing 3306 at some internal IP address.

There are also other services, like DNS resolution on port 53, samba for file-sharing, ice-cast for audio-streaming and some other services.

We are planning to do a re-design of the backing services. I was thinking that instead of setting up a new MySQL in a new IP or port and then re-route the 35 workstations to the new system, I thought to put some kind of MySQL proxy/gateway in the existing IP/port and run the old server in a new port, and then make the proxy to redirect que queries to the old MySQL server (running in a new port). Then, at will, when I want to mutate to the new system, I could just switch the proxy/gateway redirection and I would not have to change the client's configuration.

But as this has to be done with multiple services with different protocols, I wondered if there's any open-source tool which acts as a generic TCP/IP proxy for "anything" that arrives at a certain port, whatever protocol is it, much as a NAT would do but from the user-space instead of in the kernel space.

## Netcat. Is it a good candidate?

I thought about `netcat`. The manpage says:

> The nc (or netcat) utility is used for just about anything under the sun involving TCP or UDP. It can open TCP connections, send UDP packets, listen on arbitrary TCP and UDP ports, do port scanning, and deal with both IPv4 and IPv6.

## ssh-like tunnels

In fact what I think is very similar to what SSH tunnels are: Just connect to A:3333 and "transparently" get into B:7777 and it just works. With the difference that no ssh would be involved here.

## Example

Run a service in machine A, port 3306 and make it "forward" all incoming data to "remote IP of machine B port 9999" then the bytes coming back from 9999, spit them out from 3306.

Maybe I just have to have "netcat" listening in port 3306 and "create a tunnel" to B:9999.

What confuses me is that the manpage of `netcat` says that "-X proxy_version" is to set socks-4 socks-5 or http-proxy, and I feel I need a level below that. I don't know if `netcat` can just "transparently" tunnel from here to there.

## In docker?

If I can manage to just do a "software listening at port X" then it could be even dockerized and run as many instances as I wish and, provided it is protocol-agnostic (just passes the bytes thru, doing anything extra) everything just would work. The docker container would run the `nc` in the same port (say port 5000) and use the `docker run` to map the "real listening port". Then maybe the "destination" would be just an env var.

Something like:

```
docker run -d -p 3306:5000 -e REMOTE=my-other-mysql-hostname:3307 some-kind-of-proxy
```

## We control everything if needed

We control all the backing services as well as the clients, it's an in-house setup on a LAN and we have root access to wherever we want and there are no security issues involving hackers from the worls as this runs on a firewalled LAN. For example if the MySQL has to change the "allowed IPs" to be the one of the machine doing the proxy instead of those of the clients, we can do that with no problem.

## Question

- Should I run "netcat" or something similar for this goal?
- Can I do a user-space proxy instead of using iptables?
- Any ready-to-go docker image that just makes a TCP-IP tunnel on a port?

Comment: Have you also looked into nginx (https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/#proxy_pass)?

Comment: No, I did not know that nginx can do a raw TCP tunnel, I thought any proxy there would be an http proxy, not a raw proxy. It seems interesting, although a full nginx just for that feature seems an overkill. Good to know that it can do it, so if no "simpler lighter solution" comes out, will be worth trying. It seems a "good add-on to have for a system already needing an nginx" although it seems a bit too much to have a full nginx if nothing relates to http here. Thanks for the hint! Will look at it deeper!